# Can you execute a C# function/code in ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to build and ASP.NET website that will apply different filters to uploaded photos.
I've done file uploading, and C# does not seem to be much harder than PHP, and I've got formulas for filters, but what I don't know is that can I run an actual C# code on APS.NET website? Say, the way JavaScript code is being executed when the page is already loaded.
Or, maybe, I can execute my C# program on a server with some kind of call via ASP.NET? It would be worse though because I don't see how can I make a progress bar and other small features.

Comment: You can execute any kind of application on your server on user/browser request

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible since C# programs are compiled and cannot be executed in front-end like JavaScript or Java applets some years ago.

You can though execute any C# program you like on your server which hosts you ASP .NET website. Then you can return result of your program to the client.

Progress bar should be done with JavaScript. You can ask server from client side (with AJAX and JS) what's the progress of server side operation and return it to front-end progress bar.

See it as: C# is on server and JS, HTML etc. are on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have access to the library of that particular C# code instead of the executable? if you indeed have, then it's better to call that library instead. However, if you don't have access to the library you can use [ProcessStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)
alongside with [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx) to run your c# executable in your server.

Comment: Yes, I have the source code, though, I don't get what 'call the library' means.
ProcessStart and ProcessStartInfo seems a viable choice though.

Comment: If you have the source code of the C# program, then that's better. You can  include the code of your program to your solution as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx). You can follow the instruction in the "Adding References to a Project in a Web Site in Visual Web Developer Express" section. While it stated for Visual Web Developer Express, it is doable in standard Visual Studio

Comment: I don't quite understand what it does. Will that allow me to execute that code after the page is loaded?

Comment: Can I just call the needed function on some event? Like button clicked, file finished uploading, etc?